# Changing style in Azure Maps slow

Tags: azure, azure-maps

I got an Azure Map and I have implemented a custom "change style" button that when pressed calls [map.setStyle()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/azure-maps-control/atlas.map?view=azure-maps-typescript-latest#setstyle-styleoptions-). When I call this function using 'satellite' the switch is very quick. Like this:

```
map.setStyle({ 'style': 'satellite' });
```

But when I change the style "back" to 'road' the switch is super slow. Like this:

```
 map.setStyle({ 'style': 'road' });
```

Am I doing something wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The road layer has to load the styling layers for rendering the map, where as the satellite layer only renders image tiles with no road data. The team is working on loading performance of the base map styles which should help with this. Don't have an exact ETA yet but likely in the next few months.